# Define a new CoefficientDomain in PolynomialReduce function

Tags: polynomials, groebner-bases

If we have some parameter like $q_1, q_2,...,q_n$,

I would like to define a new CoefficientDomain for PolynomialReduce function such that get these parameters as integers,

In the other words, CoefficientDomain -> Integers $\cup \{q_1, q_2,...,q_n\}$

or $Q[q_1, q_2,...,q_n]$

EX: Let **set** ba a set of m polynomials in `{k02,k03,k05,k06,k12,k13,k21,k31,k45,k46,k52,k54,k63,k64,q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14}`.

```
set={-k21 + q7, k13 - q6, k21 + k31 - q7 - q8, 
 k02 + k12 + k52 - q1 - q11 - q5, 
 k02 k21 + k12 k21 + k21 k52 - q1 q7 - q11 q7 - q5 q7, -k03 - k13 - 
  k63 + q13 + q2 + q6, -k03 k21 - k13 k21 - k21 k63 + q13 q7 + q2 q7 +
   q6 q7, -k02 - k12 - k52 - q1 - q11 - q5, 
 k05 k06 k13 k54 + k05 k13 k46 k54 + k05 k06 k13 k64 + 
  k06 k13 k45 k64 - q10 q12 q3 q6 - q12 q3 q4 q6 - q14 q3 q4 q6 - 
  q14 q4 q6 q9, -k05 k13 - k06 k13 - k13 k45 - k13 k46 + q10 q6 + 
  q3 q6 + q4 q6 + q6 q9, -k05 k06 k13 - k06 k13 k45 - k05 k13 k46 - 
  k13 k45 k46 + q10 q3 q6 + q3 q4 q6 + q10 q6 q9 + q4 q6 q9, 
 k03 + k13 + k21 + k31 + k63 - q13 - q2 - q6 - q7 - q8, 
 k03 k46 k63 - k05 k46 k63 + k13 k46 k63 - k45 k46 k63 + k46 k63^2 - 
  q10 q13^2 - q10 q13 q2 + q10 q13 q3 - q10 q13 q6 + q10 q13 q9, 
 k03 k21 - k12 k21 + k13 k21 + k03 k31 + k21 k63 + k31 k63 - q13 q7 - 
  q2 q7 + q5 q7 - q6 q7 - q13 q8 - q2 q8, 
 k02 k12 - k03 k12 + k12^2 - k12 k13 + k12 k52 - k12 k63 - q1 q5 - 
  q11 q5 + q13 q5 + q2 q5 - q5^2 + q5 q6, 
 k05 k13 + k06 k13 + k13 k45 + k13 k46 + k13 k54 + k13 k64 - q10 q6 - 
  q12 q6 - q14 q6 - q3 q6 - q4 q6 - q6 q9, 
 k02 k21 + k03 k21 + k12 k21 + k13 k21 + k21^2 + k21 k31 + k21 k52 + 
  k21 k63 - q1 q7 - q11 q7 - q13 q7 - q2 q7 - q5 q7 - q6 q7 - q7^2 - 
  q7 q8, k05 k06 k13 + k06 k13 k45 + k05 k13 k46 + k13 k45 k46 + 
  k05 k13 k54 + k06 k13 k54 + k13 k46 k54 + k05 k13 k64 + 
  k06 k13 k64 + k13 k45 k64 - q10 q12 q6 - q10 q3 q6 - q12 q3 q6 - 
  q14 q3 q6 - q12 q4 q6 - q14 q4 q6 - q3 q4 q6 - q10 q6 q9 - 
  q14 q6 q9 - q4 q6 q9, -k13 k21 k45 k52 + k03 k21 k46 k63 - 
  k05 k21 k46 k63 + k13 k21 k46 k63 + k03 k31 k46 k63 - 
  k05 k31 k46 k63 - k21 k45 k46 k63 - k31 k45 k46 k63 + 
  k21 k46 k63^2 + k31 k46 k63^2 - q10 q13^2 q7 - q10 q13 q2 q7 + 
  q10 q13 q3 q7 - q10 q13 q6 q7 - q10 q13^2 q8 - q10 q13 q2 q8 + 
  q10 q13 q3 q8 + q10 q13 q7 q9 + q11 q6 q7 q9 + q10 q13 q8 q9, 
 k02 k13 k45 k52 - k06 k13 k45 k52 + k12 k13 k45 k52 - 
  k13 k45 k46 k52 + k13 k45 k52^2 - k03 k12 k46 k63 + 
  k05 k12 k46 k63 - k12 k13 k46 k63 + k12 k45 k46 k63 - 
  k12 k46 k63^2 + q10 q13^2 q5 + q10 q13 q2 q5 - q10 q13 q3 q5 + 
  q10 q13 q5 q6 - q10 q13 q5 q9 - q1 q11 q6 q9 + q10 q11 q6 q9 - 
  q11^2 q6 q9 + q11 q4 q6 q9 - q11 q5 q6 q9, -k02^2 k21 - 
  2 k02 k12 k21 - k12^2 k21 + k03 k21^2 - k12 k21^2 + k13 k21^2 + 
  k03 k21 k31 - 2 k02 k21 k52 - 2 k12 k21 k52 - k21 k52^2 + 
  k21^2 k63 + k21 k31 k63 + q1^2 q7 + 2 q1 q11 q7 + q11^2 q7 + 
  2 q1 q5 q7 + 2 q11 q5 q7 + q5^2 q7 - q13 q7^2 - q2 q7^2 + q5 q7^2 - 
  q6 q7^2 - q13 q7 q8 - q2 q7 q8, 
 k03^2 + 2 k03 k13 + k13^2 + k03 k21 + k13 k21 + k03 k31 + k13 k31 + 
  2 k03 k63 + 2 k13 k63 + k21 k63 + k31 k63 + k63^2 - q13^2 - 
  2 q13 q2 - q2^2 - 2 q13 q6 - 2 q2 q6 - q6^2 - q13 q7 - q2 q7 - 
  q6 q7 - q13 q8 - q2 q8 - q6 q8, 
 k02^3 + 3 k02^2 k12 + 3 k02 k12^2 + k12^3 + k02 k12 k21 - 
  k03 k12 k21 + k12^2 k21 - k12 k13 k21 + 3 k02^2 k52 + 
  6 k02 k12 k52 + 3 k12^2 k52 + k12 k21 k52 + 3 k02 k52^2 + 
  3 k12 k52^2 + k52^3 - k12 k21 k63 - q1^3 - 3 q1^2 q11 - 3 q1 q11^2 -
   q11^3 - 3 q1^2 q5 - 6 q1 q11 q5 - 3 q11^2 q5 - 3 q1 q5^2 - 
  3 q11 q5^2 - q5^3 - q1 q5 q7 - q11 q5 q7 + q13 q5 q7 + q2 q5 q7 - 
  q5^2 q7 + q5 q6 q7, -k03^2 - 2 k03 k13 - k13^2 - k03 k21 - k12 k21 -
   k13 k21 - k21^2 - k03 k31 - 2 k13 k31 - 2 k21 k31 - k31^2 - 
  2 k03 k63 - 2 k13 k63 - k21 k63 - k31 k63 - k63^2 + q13^2 + 
  2 q13 q2 + q2^2 + 2 q13 q6 + 2 q2 q6 + q6^2 + q13 q7 + q2 q7 + 
  q5 q7 + q6 q7 + q7^2 + q13 q8 + q2 q8 + 2 q6 q8 + 2 q7 q8 + 
  q8^2, -k03^2 k21 + k02 k12 k21 + k12^2 k21 - 2 k03 k13 k21 - 
  k13^2 k21 - k03 k21^2 + k12 k21^2 - k13 k21^2 - k03^2 k31 - 
  k03 k13 k31 - 2 k03 k21 k31 + k12 k21 k31 - k13 k21 k31 - 
  k03 k31^2 + k12 k21 k52 - 2 k03 k21 k63 - 2 k13 k21 k63 - 
  k21^2 k63 - 2 k03 k31 k63 - k13 k31 k63 - 2 k21 k31 k63 - 
  k31^2 k63 - k21 k63^2 - k31 k63^2 + q13^2 q7 + 2 q13 q2 q7 + 
  q2^2 q7 - q1 q5 q7 - q11 q5 q7 - q5^2 q7 + 2 q13 q6 q7 + 
  2 q2 q6 q7 + q6^2 q7 + q13 q7^2 + q2 q7^2 - q5 q7^2 + q6 q7^2 + 
  q13^2 q8 + 2 q13 q2 q8 + q2^2 q8 + q13 q6 q8 + q2 q6 q8 + 
  2 q13 q7 q8 + 2 q2 q7 q8 - q5 q7 q8 + q6 q7 q8 + q13 q8^2 + 
  q2 q8^2, -k02^2 k12 + k03^2 k12 - 2 k02 k12^2 - k12^3 + 
  2 k03 k12 k13 + k12 k13^2 - k02 k12 k31 + k03 k12 k31 - k12^2 k31 + 
  k12 k13 k31 - 2 k02 k12 k52 - 2 k12^2 k52 - k12 k31 k52 - 
  k12 k52^2 + 2 k03 k12 k63 + 2 k12 k13 k63 + k12 k31 k63 + 
  k12 k63^2 + q1^2 q5 + 2 q1 q11 q5 + q11^2 q5 - q13^2 q5 - 
  2 q13 q2 q5 - q2^2 q5 + 2 q1 q5^2 + 2 q11 q5^2 + q5^3 - 
  2 q13 q5 q6 - 2 q2 q5 q6 - q5 q6^2 - k02 k12 q7 + k03 k12 q7 - 
  k12^2 q7 + k12 k13 q7 - k12 k52 q7 + k12 k63 q7 + q1 q5 q7 + 
  q11 q5 q7 - q13 q5 q7 - q2 q5 q7 + q5^2 q7 - q5 q6 q7 + q1 q5 q8 + 
  q11 q5 q8 - q13 q5 q8 - q2 q5 q8 + q5^2 q8 - q5 q6 q8}
```

I would like to find

```
m = Length[set]
For[i = 1, i <= m, i++,
 For[j = i + 1, j <= m, j++,
  set[[j]] = 
   PolynomialReduce[set[[j]], 
     set[[i]], {k02, k03, k05, k06, k12, k13, k21, k31, k45, k46, k52,
       k54, k63, k64}, CoefficientDomain -> Rationals][[2]]]]
```

Such that we consider `{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6, q7, q8, q9, q10, q11, q12, q13, q14}` as integers.

Comment: (1) My suggestion would be to make the parameters into variables, ordered lower than all actual variables, and use a block order with the higher block for the variable ordering and the lower for the parameters, say in DegreeReverseLexicographic.

Comment: (2) This really should be accompanied by a concrete example with cut-and-pastable input and an indication of the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your answers

could you please give me some examples?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau

Actually, I have never used block order, please introduce me a reference

Comment: If you post a concrete example I can post a response with some code to construct a block order.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I really appreciate your consideration

Comment: To be a full example this needs an explicit set of polynomials for `set`. I don't suppose a complete interreduction is what's wanted?

Comment: actually, I would like to reduce this sentence such that I could find Groebnerbasis of them without changing solution

Comment: Thanks for providing the full example. There is something I only just now noticed. You are asking for a GB computed over the rationals Q, but with the parameters regarded as integer-valued. Unless I am badly mistaken, this last consideration does not actually change the GB. It is only when you want the GB over the integers that a change in coefficient domain is required. Anyway, I'll post some possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this self contained I will copy the somewhat large input from the question.

```
set = {-k21 + q7, k13 - q6, k21 + k31 - q7 - q8, 
  k02 + k12 + k52 - q1 - q11 - q5, 
  k02 k21 + k12 k21 + k21 k52 - q1 q7 - q11 q7 - q5 q7, -k03 - k13 - 
   k63 + q13 + q2 + q6, -k03 k21 - k13 k21 - k21 k63 + q13 q7 + 
   q2 q7 + q6 q7, -k02 - k12 - k52 - q1 - q11 - q5, 
  k05 k06 k13 k54 + k05 k13 k46 k54 + k05 k06 k13 k64 + 
   k06 k13 k45 k64 - q10 q12 q3 q6 - q12 q3 q4 q6 - q14 q3 q4 q6 - 
   q14 q4 q6 q9, -k05 k13 - k06 k13 - k13 k45 - k13 k46 + q10 q6 + 
   q3 q6 + q4 q6 + q6 q9, -k05 k06 k13 - k06 k13 k45 - k05 k13 k46 - 
   k13 k45 k46 + q10 q3 q6 + q3 q4 q6 + q10 q6 q9 + q4 q6 q9, 
  k03 + k13 + k21 + k31 + k63 - q13 - q2 - q6 - q7 - q8, 
  k03 k46 k63 - k05 k46 k63 + k13 k46 k63 - k45 k46 k63 + k46 k63^2 - 
   q10 q13^2 - q10 q13 q2 + q10 q13 q3 - q10 q13 q6 + q10 q13 q9, 
  k03 k21 - k12 k21 + k13 k21 + k03 k31 + k21 k63 + k31 k63 - q13 q7 -
    q2 q7 + q5 q7 - q6 q7 - q13 q8 - q2 q8, 
  k02 k12 - k03 k12 + k12^2 - k12 k13 + k12 k52 - k12 k63 - q1 q5 - 
   q11 q5 + q13 q5 + q2 q5 - q5^2 + q5 q6, 
  k05 k13 + k06 k13 + k13 k45 + k13 k46 + k13 k54 + k13 k64 - q10 q6 -
    q12 q6 - q14 q6 - q3 q6 - q4 q6 - q6 q9, 
  k02 k21 + k03 k21 + k12 k21 + k13 k21 + k21^2 + k21 k31 + k21 k52 + 
   k21 k63 - q1 q7 - q11 q7 - q13 q7 - q2 q7 - q5 q7 - q6 q7 - q7^2 - 
   q7 q8, k05 k06 k13 + k06 k13 k45 + k05 k13 k46 + k13 k45 k46 + 
   k05 k13 k54 + k06 k13 k54 + k13 k46 k54 + k05 k13 k64 + 
   k06 k13 k64 + k13 k45 k64 - q10 q12 q6 - q10 q3 q6 - q12 q3 q6 - 
   q14 q3 q6 - q12 q4 q6 - q14 q4 q6 - q3 q4 q6 - q10 q6 q9 - 
   q14 q6 q9 - q4 q6 q9, -k13 k21 k45 k52 + k03 k21 k46 k63 - 
   k05 k21 k46 k63 + k13 k21 k46 k63 + k03 k31 k46 k63 - 
   k05 k31 k46 k63 - k21 k45 k46 k63 - k31 k45 k46 k63 + 
   k21 k46 k63^2 + k31 k46 k63^2 - q10 q13^2 q7 - q10 q13 q2 q7 + 
   q10 q13 q3 q7 - q10 q13 q6 q7 - q10 q13^2 q8 - q10 q13 q2 q8 + 
   q10 q13 q3 q8 + q10 q13 q7 q9 + q11 q6 q7 q9 + q10 q13 q8 q9, 
  k02 k13 k45 k52 - k06 k13 k45 k52 + k12 k13 k45 k52 - 
   k13 k45 k46 k52 + k13 k45 k52^2 - k03 k12 k46 k63 + 
   k05 k12 k46 k63 - k12 k13 k46 k63 + k12 k45 k46 k63 - 
   k12 k46 k63^2 + q10 q13^2 q5 + q10 q13 q2 q5 - q10 q13 q3 q5 + 
   q10 q13 q5 q6 - q10 q13 q5 q9 - q1 q11 q6 q9 + q10 q11 q6 q9 - 
   q11^2 q6 q9 + q11 q4 q6 q9 - q11 q5 q6 q9, -k02^2 k21 - 
   2 k02 k12 k21 - k12^2 k21 + k03 k21^2 - k12 k21^2 + k13 k21^2 + 
   k03 k21 k31 - 2 k02 k21 k52 - 2 k12 k21 k52 - k21 k52^2 + 
   k21^2 k63 + k21 k31 k63 + q1^2 q7 + 2 q1 q11 q7 + q11^2 q7 + 
   2 q1 q5 q7 + 2 q11 q5 q7 + q5^2 q7 - q13 q7^2 - q2 q7^2 + q5 q7^2 -
    q6 q7^2 - q13 q7 q8 - q2 q7 q8, 
  k03^2 + 2 k03 k13 + k13^2 + k03 k21 + k13 k21 + k03 k31 + k13 k31 + 
   2 k03 k63 + 2 k13 k63 + k21 k63 + k31 k63 + k63^2 - q13^2 - 
   2 q13 q2 - q2^2 - 2 q13 q6 - 2 q2 q6 - q6^2 - q13 q7 - q2 q7 - 
   q6 q7 - q13 q8 - q2 q8 - q6 q8, 
  k02^3 + 3 k02^2 k12 + 3 k02 k12^2 + k12^3 + k02 k12 k21 - 
   k03 k12 k21 + k12^2 k21 - k12 k13 k21 + 3 k02^2 k52 + 
   6 k02 k12 k52 + 3 k12^2 k52 + k12 k21 k52 + 3 k02 k52^2 + 
   3 k12 k52^2 + k52^3 - k12 k21 k63 - q1^3 - 3 q1^2 q11 - 
   3 q1 q11^2 - q11^3 - 3 q1^2 q5 - 6 q1 q11 q5 - 3 q11^2 q5 - 
   3 q1 q5^2 - 3 q11 q5^2 - q5^3 - q1 q5 q7 - q11 q5 q7 + q13 q5 q7 + 
   q2 q5 q7 - q5^2 q7 + q5 q6 q7, -k03^2 - 2 k03 k13 - k13^2 - 
   k03 k21 - k12 k21 - k13 k21 - k21^2 - k03 k31 - 2 k13 k31 - 
   2 k21 k31 - k31^2 - 2 k03 k63 - 2 k13 k63 - k21 k63 - k31 k63 - 
   k63^2 + q13^2 + 2 q13 q2 + q2^2 + 2 q13 q6 + 2 q2 q6 + q6^2 + 
   q13 q7 + q2 q7 + q5 q7 + q6 q7 + q7^2 + q13 q8 + q2 q8 + 2 q6 q8 + 
   2 q7 q8 + q8^2, -k03^2 k21 + k02 k12 k21 + k12^2 k21 - 
   2 k03 k13 k21 - k13^2 k21 - k03 k21^2 + k12 k21^2 - k13 k21^2 - 
   k03^2 k31 - k03 k13 k31 - 2 k03 k21 k31 + k12 k21 k31 - 
   k13 k21 k31 - k03 k31^2 + k12 k21 k52 - 2 k03 k21 k63 - 
   2 k13 k21 k63 - k21^2 k63 - 2 k03 k31 k63 - k13 k31 k63 - 
   2 k21 k31 k63 - k31^2 k63 - k21 k63^2 - k31 k63^2 + q13^2 q7 + 
   2 q13 q2 q7 + q2^2 q7 - q1 q5 q7 - q11 q5 q7 - q5^2 q7 + 
   2 q13 q6 q7 + 2 q2 q6 q7 + q6^2 q7 + q13 q7^2 + q2 q7^2 - q5 q7^2 +
    q6 q7^2 + q13^2 q8 + 2 q13 q2 q8 + q2^2 q8 + q13 q6 q8 + 
   q2 q6 q8 + 2 q13 q7 q8 + 2 q2 q7 q8 - q5 q7 q8 + q6 q7 q8 + 
   q13 q8^2 + q2 q8^2, -k02^2 k12 + k03^2 k12 - 2 k02 k12^2 - k12^3 + 
   2 k03 k12 k13 + k12 k13^2 - k02 k12 k31 + k03 k12 k31 - k12^2 k31 +
    k12 k13 k31 - 2 k02 k12 k52 - 2 k12^2 k52 - k12 k31 k52 - 
   k12 k52^2 + 2 k03 k12 k63 + 2 k12 k13 k63 + k12 k31 k63 + 
   k12 k63^2 + q1^2 q5 + 2 q1 q11 q5 + q11^2 q5 - q13^2 q5 - 
   2 q13 q2 q5 - q2^2 q5 + 2 q1 q5^2 + 2 q11 q5^2 + q5^3 - 
   2 q13 q5 q6 - 2 q2 q5 q6 - q5 q6^2 - k02 k12 q7 + k03 k12 q7 - 
   k12^2 q7 + k12 k13 q7 - k12 k52 q7 + k12 k63 q7 + q1 q5 q7 + 
   q11 q5 q7 - q13 q5 q7 - q2 q5 q7 + q5^2 q7 - q5 q6 q7 + q1 q5 q8 + 
   q11 q5 q8 - q13 q5 q8 - q2 q5 q8 + q5^2 q8 - q5 q6 q8};
```

The variables are the "kij" and the "qij" symbols are to be regarded as parameters. There are 26 polynomials and 14 each of the variables and parameters. The system is overdetermined for generic values of parameters. Taking a wild guess, we want to find an integer modulus so that the system has a nontrivial Groebner basis (GB).

Computing a GB over the integers is likely to be an expensive operation. I'll show how to do a full interreduction instead. Since we want to treat parameters as lower in term order than variables, we should use a weight matrix for the term ordering that enforces this relation. For speed I chose to use the degree reverse lexicographic term order for both variables and parameters. This term order can readily be represented as a weight matrix (even though it is also a built-in ordering understood by GB). The block order in effect creates a new matrix with each individual term order as a diagonal block.

In order to have all this in one place, I show code to create weight matrices for all the build in term orders.

```
drlMatrix[n_] := Prepend[
  Table[-KroneckerDelta[j + k - (n + 1)], {j, n - 1}, {k, n}], 
  Table[1, {n}]]

dlMatrix[n_] := Prepend[
  Table[KroneckerDelta[j - k], {j, n - 1}, {k, n}], Table[1, {n}]]

elimMatrix[n1_, n2_] := Module[
  {row1, rest},
  row1 = Join[Table[1, {n1}], Table[0, {n2 - n1}]];
  rest = drlMatrix[n2];
  rest = Drop[rest, {n2 - n1 + 1}];
  Prepend[rest, row1]]

blockMatrix[m1_, m2_] := ArrayFlatten[{{m1, 0}, {0, m2}}]
blockMatrix[m1_, m2_, m3__] :=
  blockMatrix[m1, blockMatrix[m2, m3]]
```

We could iterate reducing each polynomial by others, but there is actually an undocumented function to do a full interreduction. We use that, with coefficient domain set to integers, and term ordering that places parameters lower than variables.

```
vars = {k02, k03, k05, k06, k12, k13, k21, k31, k45, k46, k52, k54, 
   k63, k64};
params = Complement[Variables[set], vars];

orderMatrix = 
  blockMatrix[drlMatrix[Length[vars]], drlMatrix[Length[params]]];

reducedSet = 
 GroebnerBasis`Interreduce[set, Join[vars, params], 
  MonomialOrder -> orderMatrix, CoefficientDomain -> Integers]

(* Out[96]= {-2 q1 - 2 q11 - 2 q5, 
 k54 q6 + k64 q6 - q12 q6 - q14 q6, -k31 + q8, k21 - q7, 
 k13 - q6, -k12 q7 + q5 q7, 
 k12 q1 + k12 q11 - k12 q13 - k12 q2 + k12 q5 + q1 q5 + q11 q5 + 
  q13 q5 + q2 q5 + q5^2 - k12 q6 + q5 q6, 
 k05 q6 + k06 q6 + k45 q6 + k46 q6 - q10 q6 - q3 q6 - q4 q6 - q6 q9, 
 k03 + k63 - q13 - q2, k02 + k12 + k52 + q1 + q11 + q5, 
 k45 k64 q6 - k46 k64 q6 - k45 q12 q6 - k45 q14 q6 + q10 q14 q6 + 
  q12 q6 q9, 
 k45 k52 q6 q7 + k46 k63 q6 q8 - q10 q13 q6 q8 - 
  q11 q6 q7 q9, -k06^2 q6 - 2 k06 k46 q6 - k46^2 q6 + k06 q10 q6 + 
  k46 q10 q6 + k06 q3 q6 + k46 q3 q6 - q10 q3 q6 + k06 q4 q6 + 
  k46 q4 q6 - q3 q4 q6 + k06 q6 q9 + k46 q6 q9 - q10 q6 q9 - q4 q6 q9,
  2 k06 k46 k64 q6 + 2 k46^2 k64 q6 - k46 k64 q10 q6 - 
  k06 q10 q14 q6 - k46 q10 q14 q6 - k46 k64 q3 q6 + q10 q14 q3 q6 - 
  k46 k64 q4 q6 - k46 k64 q6 q9 - k06 q12 q6 q9 - k46 q12 q6 q9 + 
  q10 q12 q6 q9 + q10 q14 q6 q9 + q12 q4 q6 q9, -k05 k46 k63 - 
  k45 k46 k63 + k46 k63 q13 - q10 q13^2 + k46 k63 q2 - q10 q13 q2 + 
  q10 q13 q3 + k46 k63 q6 - q10 q13 q6 + q10 q13 q9, -k12 q10 q13^2 - 
  k12 q10 q13 q2 + k12 q10 q13 q3 + q10 q13^2 q5 + q10 q13 q2 q5 - 
  q10 q13 q3 q5 - k06 k45 k52 q6 - k45 k46 k52 q6 + k45 k52 q1 q6 + 
  k45 k52 q11 q6 - k12 q10 q13 q6 + k45 k52 q5 q6 + q10 q13 q5 q6 + 
  k12 q10 q13 q9 - q10 q13 q5 q9 + q1 q11 q6 q9 + q10 q11 q6 q9 + 
  q11^2 q6 q9 + q11 q4 q6 q9 + q11 q5 q6 q9} *)
```

I do not know if this is the hoped-for or expected outcome but I hope at least the code is useful.

Comment: I profoundly appreciate your help, It was very kind of you

Anyway, I need more time to test this method, 
Also, I would be grateful if you could introduce function "GroebnerBasis`Interreduce" to me

Comment: Function "GroebnerBasis`Interreduce" is so faster than GroebnerBasis and when I use CoefficientDomain -> RationalFunctions
the answers are the same.
What is the reason for this speed?

Comment: It is doing a full interreduction but not attempting to compute a GB (so no S-polynomials or critical pairs are created or reduced).